# Android image localisation in Xamarin Form

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin Form application which has a language dropdown so user can select the application language. When user select a language I call:

```
            CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(language);
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = culture;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
            AppResources.Culture = culture;
```

The application works fine and picks the strings from **AppResources.{language}.resx**
My problem is when localising an image. As per Microsoft's suggestion I have added my image to Resources/drawable folders inside the android project. In my case, I added thanks.jpg to **Resources/drawable** and **Resources/drawable-fr**. But it only shows the image on Resources/drawable folder even when I select fr-FR as language, however I found out if instead of changing the application language(culture), I change the device language, the device show the correct image(the image inside Resources/drawable-fr). I was wondering if there is any way to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a dependence service to fix it.

First of all, create a interface.

```
    public interface IChangeService
    {
        void ChangeIanguage(string lang);
    }
```

We used it in the this format code in the xamarin forms.

```
  <StackLayout>
        <TimePicker></TimePicker>
        <Image WidthRequest="100">
            <Image.Source>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="ImageSource">
                    <On Platform="iOS, Android" Value="flag.png" />
                    <On Platform="UWP" Value="Assets/Images/flag.png" />
                </OnPlatform>
            </Image.Source>
            </Image>
            <Button Text="Change" Clicked="Button_Clicked"></Button>
    </StackLayout>
```

Here is background code.

```
 public partial class LocalizedXamlPage : ContentPage
    {
        public LocalizedXamlPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            DependencyService.Get<IChangeService>().ChangeIanguage("en");
        }
    }
```

Then achieve the interface in the android platform. If we change the localization, we need it to work at the runtime, we should restart our application.

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(ChangeLanguageService))]
namespace UsingResxLocalization.Droid
{
    public class ChangeLanguageService : IChangeService
    {
        public void ChangeIanguage(string lang = "in")
        {
           
            LanguageManager.ChangeLanguage(MainActivity.instance, lang);
            //restart your application.
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.instance, typeof(MainActivity));
            intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTask | ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            MainActivity.instance.StartActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Then we need to create a `BaseActivity`(because we change the `Locale` in android, we should use the same Context.) and `LanguageManager`(change the localization at the runtime)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Java.Util;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

namespace UsingResxLocalization.Droid
{
    public class BaseActivity : FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void AttachBaseContext(Context @base)
        {
            base.AttachBaseContext(LanguageManager.LoadLanguage(@base));
        }

    }

    public class LanguageManager
    {
        private const string MYLANGUAGE = "myLanguage";
        private const string MYPREF = "myPreference";

        public static Context LoadLanguage(Context context)
        {
            var loadedLanguage = GetLanguage(context, Locale.Default.Language);
            return ChangeLanguage(context, loadedLanguage);
        }

        public static Context ChangeLanguage(Context context, string language)
        {
            SaveLanguage(context, language);
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.N)
            {
                return ChangeForAPI24(context, language);
            }
            return ChangeForLegacy(context, language);
        }

        private static string GetLanguage(Context context, string Language)
        {
            var privatePreference = context.GetSharedPreferences(MYPREF, FileCreationMode.Private);
            return privatePreference.GetString(MYLANGUAGE, Language);
        }

        private static void SaveLanguage(Context context, string language)
        {
            var privatePreference = context.GetSharedPreferences(MYPREF, FileCreationMode.Private);
            var editor = privatePreference.Edit();
            editor.PutString(MYLANGUAGE, language);
            editor.Apply();
        }

        private static Context ChangeForAPI24(Context context, string language)
        {
            // for api >= 24
            var locale = new Locale(language);
            Locale.Default = locale;
            var configuration = context.Resources.Configuration;
            configuration.SetLocale(locale);
            configuration.SetLayoutDirection(locale);

            return context.CreateConfigurationContext(configuration);
        }

        private static Context ChangeForLegacy(Context context, string language)
        {
            var locale = new Locale(language);
            Locale.Default = locale;
            var resources = context.Resources;
            var configuration = resources.Configuration;
            configuration.Locale = locale;
            resources.UpdateConfiguration(configuration, resources.DisplayMetrics);
            return context;
        }
    }
}
```

To make the mainAcitvity extend the `BaseActivity.cs`. And expose the  `public static MainActivity instance;`,

```
 [Activity(Label = "UsingResxLocalization", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : BaseActivity
    {
        public static MainActivity instance;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
            instance = this;
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
    }
```

Here is runinng GIF.

[image]

========Update=========

I make a test with France flag by changing language to fr when the device language is English.

I upload my demo to you, you can test it.

https://github.com/851265601/LocalzationDemo/blob/master/LocalzationDemoWithFlag.zip

If you want to change the text of Button or other label, when you click the Button, Please add `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("fr", false);` as well in the click event. You can see this GIF.

[image]

Comment: if above answer is helpful, please do not forget to accept it as answer(click the “✔” in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue

Comment: It does not work for me. Let's make it simple. I want to see France flag by changing language to fr when the device language is English. I tried ChangeForAPI24 as well as ChangeForLegacy but none of them works

Comment: I make a test with  France flag with my demo, it worked. You can see my update answer.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT For better clarification can you change the language of the text of button displayed? it's just showing flag change but confusing that it really changed the language of application or not.

Comment: @Blu Thanks for your advice, I changed my answer.

Comment: That's really a helpful answer.