# Changing language in Android app results in displaying two languages including previous language

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, translation

I have developed an Android app using Xamarin.Forms. I have done translation integration. Everything works fine except when the app is open, if we change the language by going to Settings and bring the app again to the foreground, the app displays combination of two languages (one is current language and one is previous language). Is it because somewhere the previous language texts had got cached? If I quit the app and open the app again, it displays in current language only and works fine.

May I know why it displays combination of two languages and how to overcome this issue?

Comment: Please see this thread:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/text?pivots=windows#test-localization   If you change languages, you may need to exit and restart the application to see the changes applied. If you change the language at the runtime, it will make display issue.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT Thank you for the comment. So, I hope we can't do anything except instruct the user to restart the app after language change.

Comment: If User change language in system Settings, it seems we cannot do anything.If user change the language in the app, we can use my way to force our application to restart like my answer in this thread:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63683842/android-image-localisation-in-xamarin-form/63684852#63684852

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT But we have only option of changing language in system settings.

Comment: Ok, it seem that we cannot do nothing except to remind user to restart the app.